# Space under toilet base

Tags: toilet

I replaced my toilet with new one. Installed wax ring, and placed the toilet, tightened screws and had to apply few shims to stop wobbling. Toilet seems now stable and leveled, but I see too much space on one side of the toilet. See attached picture, is it normal ? Do I have to apply too much caulk now ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shimming creates a gap. You don't _have_ to caulk the bottom of a toilet, but yes, if you intend to do so you'll want to bridge that gap. I don't know if backer rod is available that small, but if it is then you can save caulk and effort by using the backer to mostly fill the gap first and then caulking in front of that.

Comment: I wouldn't apply caulk...if there is a leak, you WANT to find it!  (Others disagree).   You can trim the shims by putting a wood chisel on it and **gently** tapping down on it with a hammer.

Comment: I would caulk it to prevent "near misses" that run down the side (it happens) from collecting and festering in the void.

Comment: @SteveWellens I like to scribe or trace the edge of the bowl on the shim, mark its position, then pull it out and cut.  Then I stick it back in the same position.  Less risk of breaking anything.  Although it looks like the OP could use some regrouting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your gap is normal. Finding your old bathroom floor both flat and level would be a lucky find.

The answer to your caulking question is somewhat of an opinion.

1. You don't want water from the bathroom going down there because the floor penetration is likely not sealed, so caulking is a good idea to prevent toilet misses or incidental water (puddles from shower takers, especially kids) from getting down there.
2. On the other hand, if there is a leak under the toilet, you would like the chance of finding out before the ceiling below collapses in a soaked mush of human waste. The school of thought there is to have the leak show in the bathroom first. Now if the leak is very slow, you will probably see it in the ceil first anyway, so I argue you should only think of a faster leak when considering this.

Considering both, I recommend a hybrid approach: caulking most of the way around the toilet, leaving a small section around the back (where you probably can't see or apply caulk well anyway) open for a larger leak to show itself. Hopefully this means that water from the bathroom is only a risk in a flood situation, and by then the water getting under the toilet will just be a drop in the bucket of damage.

Comment: agree.  Funny Carpenter does a good job with this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9_N58MvqnY